# How to say "in the strict ... of the term"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, idioms, collocation

I am not quite sure if the following expression makes sense in English:

> in the strict **meaning** of the term

Is it right? Should the word *meaning* be replaced by *sense*?
The meaning of the phrase should be somehow synonymous with "strictly speaking."

A possible example would be:

> I am not a fan of Man United **in the strict meaning of the term**, since I have been in Old Trafford only once.

Comment: I don't know if it's a regional thing or not, but my ear does expect *sense*, there (and you can skip the "*of the term*", and even emphasize by saying *strictest*). I'm from the U.S., maybe the Brits will have a different opinion.

Comment: Nope, well not this one. I too expect 'sense'.  Possibly because, for me at least, the meaning of 'sense' is less categorical than the meaning of 'meaning' ;)

Comment: The slight irregularity you hear is just your inner schoolmarm saying "Hey, I haven't heard that usage before." But *sense* and *meaning* are synonyms, and there is nothing wrong with having a "strict" meaning. The usage is neither ambiguous nor confusing.

Comment: Yeah, "in the strict (or strictest) sense of the term" is what I'm most familiar with, and using "meaning" would seem very slightly "strange", though not hard to understand, and certainly not improper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not a fan of Man United **in the strictest meaning** of the <strike>term</strike> word, since I have been in Old Trafford only once.

Note the change to superlative there!

The use of *meaning* is correct here. The reference being to the meaning of the word *fan.*

Compare:

> I am not a fan of Man United **in the strictest sense** of the term, since I have been in Old Trafford only once.

The use of *sense* makes better sense here. The reference is to the popular idea of a fan, not the lexical definition.

Both words are correct. Depending on the context and the intended meaning, either word can find use.

[Use case](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6V8e94ujWBwC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22in%20the%20strictest%20sense%22%20%22in%20the%20strictest%20meaning%22&source=bl&ots=uenctKCTk0&sig=Oqb77yUQTF6s7cogeRLtXcChbZo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3wvSVLTGD9K8ugSHq4KoDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20strictest%20sense%22%20%22in%20the%20strictest%20meaning%22&f=false):

> Up to now we have considered the colors **in the strictest meaning**, namely as conditions or affections of the eye. This consideration is the first and most essential part of the color theory **in the strictest sense**, which, as such, must be the basis for all further investigations about colors and with which they always must remain in agreement.

<sup>Arthur Schopenhauer, Philipp Otto Runge: *On Vision and Colors; Color Sphere* (Google eBook) p.99</sup>

Note the use of both forms in the same paragraph, which may or may not be intentional, though.

*[In the strict(est) sense](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+strict+sense)* is idiomatic; *in the strict(est) meaning* is literal.